# Show OK / FAILED boot messages on Debian

Tags: linux, boot, debian

During my boot on Debian Jessie, I have a message beginning with "[FAILED]" in red color, but it's going too fast and I don't have the time to read what's after...

How can I display those colored messages during boot?

- `journalctl -b` won't show them,
- Tried to install bootlogd as suggested but it doesn't seem to work on recent debian installs, replaced by journalctl.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Debian, but don't you have a /var/log/boot.log with those (I do in centos).

Comment: @tonioc No, not any more.

Comment: [Where do I find boot log in Debian 8 (to debug autostart issues)?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/309447)?

Comment: maybe take a look here: https://serverfault.com/questions/516411/all-debian-boot-messages , it may help...

Comment: quick & dirty method, film it with your phone.

Comment: @Tetsujin : lol ! wonderful method !! didn't think of that and did exactly what i wanted after spending 1 hour to find a way !!

Comment: I could drop it in as an answer in case no-one comes up with an actual clever way to see the logs ;-)

Comment: Hitting `ctrl-s` should freeze the output and `ctrl-q` should resume it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Adding as an answer just because it was simple & worked ;)</sup>

Quick & dirty method, film it with your phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to record your screen, which should work in all cases, try this.

`sudo cat /var/log/boot.log`